# Reading IIS Error logs

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, error-logging, iis-logs

I need to get all the IIS errors to display on a web page.i have tried to use LogParser but could not get it working with c# code.are there any other way to read only the errors from Logs and display them on a web page?